# JAX-RS WHERE to escape response body

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have rest services (about 100 endpoints), implemented with JAX-RS Jersey. All of them have the return type "application/json", which may contain some html and javascript code, for which I need to do escaping, e.g., "<" should turn into `&lt;`. The escaping function is easy, and there are libs for that.

The trouble is, I can't find the point in the code where I should do the escaping.
I created a response like this:

```
public Response response(int response, URI location, Object entity) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder =
            Response.status(response)
                    .location(location)
                    .entity(entity);
}
```

And, I created a filter like below:

```
@Provider
public class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                   ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
    throws IOException
{
    Object entity = responseContext.getEntity();
}
}
```

`Object entity` can be of different classes. 
I believe, I need to know, when Jersey turns this object entity into a JSON String, so that I can escape that JSON string. **However,** all I have now is the `Object entity`, and I am not sure how to escape it.

I was thinking about doing entity.toString(), then escape that String and set it as entity. However, I am not sure Jersey uses toString() method to turn `entity` into JSON.

================
Example:

```
public class Person{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String description;
}
```

Actual response:

```
{"id": 1234, 
        "name": "John Doe",
        "description": "<script> Some javascript code </script>"}
```

Expected response:

```
{"id": 1234, 
    "name": "John Doe",
    "description": "&lt;script&gt; Some javascript code &lt;/script&lt;"}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape anything. The JSON marshaller, that transforms your objects to JSON, does that for you.

Comment: Just tested. No, the JSON marshaller does not escape it automatically at all.

Comment: Post an example object, containing example properties, post what you expect as output, and what you obtain as output. Post that as proper code snippets, because at the moment, you question just says: *"<" should turn into "<"*, which is not very clear. The JSON marsheller will escape what needs to be escaped in order to produce valid JSON. It won't HTML-escape, XML-escape, JavaScript-escape, or anything else. That should be done by the front-end, not by the backend.

Comment: oh, my bad. Looks like stackoverflow renders the escaping characters. It should read "<" should turn into `&lt;`

Comment: As I explained, `<` doesn't need to be escaped in JSON. So if that is displayed inside an HTML document, the code generating that document should be in charge of escaping it (that's done automatically by JS frameworks like angular, or by jquery's text() function, for example). The backend shouldn't care about that: it returns data, and the frontend (which could be anything other than HTML-based, like a mobile or desktop application), should escape when necessary. I'd say that returning HTML, and even worse, JavaScript, inside your JSON, is a design smell.

Comment: you make a good point. However, I already addressed what you said in the front end (rendering everything as TEXT). This is the case, when someone query a rest endpoint NOT through our front-end. E.g., a user opens website in one tab, say on Firefox, and then you open a new tab and query a rest end-point directly (say, using Firefox Rest Client plug-in). In such a case, the json is displayed NOT through our front-end code, but rendered directly by the plugin. And therefore, the code gets executed. Well, I did the testing, and you can try if you like. This is an extra measure towards security.

Comment: I would blame the plugin, if it executes code bundled in a JSON document. I would not change anything in my API just because a plugin isn't able to display JSON as text.

Comment: I know. Well, I wish I could just blame the plugin and get done with it :) This is part of my security protection measure.

Answer (score 0):

Your object turns to JSON at the very end, (e.g. after all your filters passed) 
So you have some options:

do escaping in each particular class getter (or setter) for fields you need to escape.

```
     public class Person{
       private long id;
       private String name;
       private String description;

       public String getDescription()
       {
         return doEscape(description);
       }
    }
```

or you can introduce your own Annotation to the field and process your entity fields accordingly in your filter... or do sometning else... There are many ways...

Main point there is that 
JSON parser at the end cares only about JSON specific escapes. For String it is only `"` character.